# Using Search Formula in Row

Tags: excel, search, row, formula

Have some problems with one of my formulas in excel.
I have an array of dates, and I want to find if any of them can be found in a cell.

E.g.

```
  C       D       F       G       H       I       J       
1 @01/31  @01/30  @01/29  @01/28  @01/27  @01/26  @01/25
```

And I have my cell A1 containing text: "I want to meet you @01/29"

I get the result I want if I do:

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(SEARCH($C$1,A1,1),0)
```

for each and every of C-J

I would like somthing like

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(SEARCH($C$1:$J$1,A1,1),0)
```

But above do not give anything.
Please help me.

What I want is one formula where I can see if the different dates in C1:J1 can be found in a sentence found in A1.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want here. Do you want one formula or seven. If one then what is the required result if two or more cells match, or isn't that possible?

Comment: I want one formula. Looking for dates in an array and them matching if one of those dates shows up in the lookup cell. In this case to see if any of dates C1:J1 can be found in Cell A1. If Date from array in A1, then 1, if there is no date, or date not in array, 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities....

An "array formula"

`=IF(COUNT(SEARCH(C1:J1,A1)),1,0)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, or a non-array version

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C1:J1,A1))+0),1,0)`

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using `Match()`. It works really well with ranges.
Something like this:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A1,C1:J1,0),0)
```

[Match MSDN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Try this for the wildcard:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("*" & A1 & "*", C1:J1 &"", 0), 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Comment: Actually... I realised I get some problems here. The Match one is not doing searched.. I get no matched =IFERROR(MATCH(A1,C1:J1,0),0), using =IFERROR(MATCH(A1,C1:J1),0) gives me all cells with text in them.. But I only want the once containing C1:J1.. And since I have other text in the cell it gets messy..

Comment: I think this is looking at it the opposite way. What I have is an array, C1:J1 with different dates in this example, that I want to see if any of them is in A1. But this Match is looking at A1 to see if it can be found in C1:J1 if I'm not misunderstanding how it works..

Comment: @Akire - I start getting what you mean :)